# Does anyone use 12.04 with HD 6950?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, radeon, compatibility, vga

Back when I first tried to switch from Windows to Ubuntu (6-7 months ago) I had several graphics related problems. The VGA was overheating, graphic glitches, video playing issues, slow/choppy window movements etc. After 2-3 reinstalls, hours of playing with different drivers/settings I decided to return to Windows :\

Now I want to give it another shot. But before I start to format, partitioning, backup and other time consuming stuff I wanted to ask if anyone using the 12.04 with HD 6950. Can I utilize the full potential of it, or the drivers are still not good enough?

I know that Linux isn't meant to play games in the first place, but the games I playing  (SC2, BLC, HoN, DotA 2) are working with wine as far as I know (or aren't?) and I can't find any reason not to switch from Windows if I can utilize the full potential of my config in Ubuntu.

So anyone who got experiences with this VGA in Ubuntu please reply. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this GPU in my machine (dual boot windows and Ubuntu) but do not play any games with it (I leave that to Windows for now). I don't have any issues with over heating or glitches, everything is smooth; the fans seem to spin up when warm and down when cool so everything should be fine for you.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) which driver do you use? I hope I won't burn the VGA, because even when I boot the installer from the CD, I can feel that the card is much warmer than in windows.

Comment: I use the stable version of CCC :) works fine for me, but I can't comment on the performance as the most it does on Ubuntu for me is youtube 
:)

Answer (score 0):

I just found this on the ATI website:

http://support.amd.com/de/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English

I haven't tried it yet but it can be the answer for ur problem ;) best of luck

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If your recommendation is simply to download and install the driver pointed to by the link, I recommend making that clear in your answer, and also explaining how to do so if you believe anyone may experience any difficulty.